# Extract the number from an element of a specified div class - Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

For the link below I want to grab the number in the box titled "Current Calculated Hashrate", and print that value.

```
<div class="panel-body" data-bind="text: hashrate() + ' H/s'">5,460.0 H/s</div>
```

The `div` class is `panel-body` and I want to extract the value of `hashrate()` from this, but I have tried with no success.

This is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = requests.get('https://xmr.nanopool.org/account/4GdoN7NCTi8a5gZug7PrwZNKjvHFmKeV11L6pNJPgj5QNEHsN6eeX3DaAQFwZ1ufD4LYCZKArktt113W7QjWvQ7CWAg4LmpcRHG1W15Y6h/001').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
H_column = soup.find('div', class_='panel-body').get('hashrate')
print (H_column)
exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see from the `data-bind="text: hashrate() + ' H/s'"` part that the text is dynamically generated. The `requests` module can't execute any script to get the dynamically generated content. `requests.get(...).text` gives you the original page source, which contains

```
<div class="panel-body" data-bind="text: hashrate() + ' H/s'"></div>
```

and not the HTML part you see while inspecting.

To overcome this problem, you can use Selenium ([for installation and demo refer this link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://xmr.nanopool.org/account/4GdoN7NCTi8a5gZug7PrwZNKjvHFmKeV11L6pNJPgj5QNEHsN6eeX3DaAQFwZ1ufD4LYCZKArktt113W7QjWvQ7CWAg4LmpcRHG1W15Y6h/001')
html = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
hashrate = soup.find('div', {'data-bind': "text: hashrate() + ' H/s'"}).text
print(hashrate)
```

Output:

> 6,930.0 H/s

Comment: I get the following error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./crawl.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File `

Comment: `"/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 856, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1464, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory`

Comment: Did you install Selenium properly, and add chromedriver to path?